# Django is deployed on a ubuntu server and cannot be “makemigrations”

Tags: python, django

I was fine when testing django locally, but when I used python `manage.py makemigrations` on a ubuntu server, I get an error

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table
>   'NewHuBu.topic_sort_model' doesn't exist")

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9CDG.png) and [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAYa8.png)

Answer (score 1):

I can see a `/` in your command.

try like

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app name not ending with slash>
```

For your case

```
python manage.py makemigrations topic
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `/` to your makemigration command.

Remove this slash and just write: `python manage.py makemigrations topic` in your case. It will work